# Python class in vscode error near unexpected token `('

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a simple class as a test in vscode.

```
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

When I use the green play button and try to instantiate from the terminal there I get the error below:

[image]

It works fine when I run the script in IDLE. Not sure what I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: It's because you're trying to run Python code in bash - the shell. Run it in a REPL instead.

Comment: VSCode is for multiple languages. You must tell it this is a python project.

Comment: Yup. Sure enough. Can't believe I missed that. SMH. Thank you! if you want to make an answer real quick. I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run Python code directly in the terminal.  YOu need to type "python" to get into the Python interpreter, and then you could type a statement like that.